# Making multiple copies of a smaller matrix into a bigger matrix

Tags: python, numpy

So suppose I have a 2by2 numpy array. I want to create another 2 by 2 numpy array so that the elements will each be the previous 2by2 array, without using an explicit for loop. How can I achieve this? The shape of the new numpy matrix should be (2,2,2,2)

Comment: A 2x2 array is not equivalent to a 2x2x2x2 array. Your question does not make sense. You should include an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `np.array([[A,A],[A,A]])` or `out = np.empty((2,2)+A.shape,A.dtype)` `out[...] = A` or `np.tile(A,(2,2,1,1))`

Answer (score 0):

**This helps you copy the numpy matrix.**
But I really did not understand your point

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix('1,2; 3,2; 3,2')
b = a.copy()
```